# Is there a way to auto-fill dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

My first problem is that I have been adding dates into the database by hand-creating them and it is labor-intensive. I am looking for a way to automatically add dates like you can do in Excel.

I have 3 columns in use.

```
Date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

TenantID (Name)

Count (Count of tenant ID)
```

This is currently what I have been using to add the dates into the database.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[acms_data]
       ([Time]
       ,[TenantId]
       ,[CallingService]
       ,[PolicyList]
       ,[PolicyInstanceList])
 VALUES
       ('2019-11-22 00:00:00'
       ,'4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2' 
       ,'s1'
       ,'p1,p2,p3,p4'
       ,'pi1,pi2,pi3,pi4')
```

I would like to know a way where instead of copy pasting each date manually, if there is a way to instead add the consecutive dates all the way to a certain range.

Example: 
11/22/01 05:30:20
.
.
.
.
11/30/01 05:30:20

I am new to SQL and I do not know what I am doing but I am willing to try all suggestion

Comment: If the `TenantId` values would be changing on each date, then there may not be a way to simplify things.  Would the values other than the date always be the same, or at least have some similarity?

Comment: Do you want to get the current date every time?

Comment: Insert the same date and after all rows are inserted, update the table. BTW, [PolicyList], [PolicyInstanceList] columns look like potential problem. Think about normalizing your schema.

Comment: You (or someone else) will likely regret the decision to store an array of items in a column (PolicyList, PolicyInstanceList).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly!

If you want to get the specific dates between rage `(N)` then you can use the below query.

```
DECLARE @TEST DATE
SET @TEST = '2019-11-22' -- your date

DECLARE @NoOfDay  INT = 9 -- No of days you want

;WITH N(N) 
AS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) M(N)
), demo(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a)
SELECT TOP(day(EOMONTH(@TEST)))
  N day, dateadd(d,N-1, @TEST) date
FROM demo
WHERE N <= @NoOfDay
```

**Output:**

```
day date
1   2019-11-22
2   2019-11-23
3   2019-11-24
4   2019-11-25
5   2019-11-26
6   2019-11-27
7   2019-11-28
8   2019-11-29
9   2019-11-30
```